# How to make background image full of page and footer stick to page bottom?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a web page to show a single article and it is powered by bootstrap framework. The page has a top nav-bar and a sidebar. The main content is put in a container. I have a background image which doesn't move as the page roll. The nav-bar is fixed to the top.

As I want to make the back image translucent, I did bunch of work and now the structure is a little confusing. Also, I want to make the footer stick to the **page bottom**, not the browser's bottom. Now the question is that, as the length of the article varies, how does the container adjust its height? I've tried to set `height: 100%`, but no use.

This is what I want:

```
|____nav_______|
| |      ||    |
| |      ||side|
| |      || bar|
| |______||    |
|_________|____|
```

However, it is like this now:

```
|______________|
| title  | |   |
| |    | | |   |
|_|    |_| |   |
| |____| | |   |
|________|_|___|
```

This is part of my markup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">... </nav>

<div class="sidebar"></div>

<div class="container-back">
    <div class="back"></div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-9" role="main" id="content">
            <div>
                <div class="post">
                    <div class="post-header">
                        <div class="post-title"></div>
                        <div class="post-header-buttom">
                            <div class="post-timestamp"></div>
                            <div class="post-tag"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="post-body font-kai">
                        content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="panel-footer">Copyright</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.back {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 2000px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background: url(images/back.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    opacity: 0.35;
    z-index: -1;
}

.col-lg-9#content {
    height: 1500px;
    margin-top: 52px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    z-index: 1;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 1500px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: auto;
}

.container-back {
    margin-top: 52px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.post {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: I‘m sorry. I'm new to HTML and I really don't know about fiddle. I've googled it and I'll give a try.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Simplify and clarify, and ask a separate question if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. add `position: relative` to `container-back` not the `container` as that is the parent element of absolutely positioned element `back`
2. add an extra closing `</dig>` tag right before `footer` to close `container-back

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have to go through all the code and do a big change.
This can solve the problem perfectly:

```
.container-back{
position: relative;
margin-top: 52px;
min-height: 1000px;
height: 100%;
width: auto;
z-index: 0;}
.back{
position: absolute;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
background: url(images/back.png);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
opacity: 0.35;
z-index: 0;}
.container{
/*padding-top: 52px;*/
height: 100%;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
width: auto;
z-index: 1;}
.col-lg-9#content{
height: 100%;
min-height: 1000px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 15px;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
/*z-index: 1;*/}
.panel-footer{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
padding: 0px;
padding-top: 3px;
width: 100%;
background: #333;
text-align: center;
font-size: small;
color: #5fdedd;
z-index: 1;
height: 25px;
line-height: 20px;}
```